# AngularJS - show which option has been selected

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to learn AngularJS and tried to create a simple shop

Now my question is, how could I make it so that it writes down which option has been selected?

```css
body {
  margin: 5em;
}
.shop {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
}
.shop .thumb {
  width: 150px;
}
.shop button {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row shop">
  <div class="thumb">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="caption post-content">
          <h4>Option1</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="post-meta">
          <button>SELECT</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="thumb">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="caption post-content">
          <h4>Option2</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="post-meta">
          <button>SELECT</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="thumb">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="caption post-content">
          <h4>Option3</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="post-meta">
          <button>SELECT</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="thumb">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="caption post-content">
          <h4>Option4</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="post-meta">
          <button>SELECT</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr />


<div class="row text-center">
  <h1>YOU HAVE SELECTED [selected option should be here]</h1>
</div>
```

Here's a codepen [link](http://goo.gl/1AdMhq):

Comment: Please include a [**minimal, complete and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) directly into your question.

Comment: You don't event have any angular in your code. Did you even try ?

Comment: @Shyju Sorry but I really just started yesterday learning angular, its been pretty hard to understand the code, I do have angular in my project, but I didn't see the need to put it in codepen

Comment: Instead of directly trying to build your business product, learn by simple samples in angular tutorials online. Start simple, practice, practice practice...

Comment: I'm not trying to build any product, I just started to learn it and needed some help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forked your codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoRrvw. 
First it's necessary that your code is surrounded by a `ng-app` .

```
<div ng-app>
   ...code...
</div>
```

Then you can add `ng-click` to your buttons and change some fields inside your scope.

```
<button ng-click="selected='optionX'">
    SELECT
</button>
```

And you can show 'selected' with `{{}}` or `ng-bind`

```
<h1>YOU HAVE SELECTED {{selected}}</h1>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

For any angular app, your page should have `ng-app` and `ng-controller` properties. We will set that in your body

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
```

Now we need to create an angular module called `myApp` and add a controller called `myCtrl` to that. The controller should have an items collection and a selectedItem property.

```
var app= angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){

  $scope.selectedItem = {name:""};
  $scope.items=[];

  //Hard coded for demo. You might get it from a service

  $scope.items.push({name:"Scott",url:"http://lorempixel.com/200/200/"});
  $scope.items.push({name:"Shyju",url:"http://lorempixel.com/200/200/"});
  $scope.items.push({name:"Brad",url: "http://lorempixel.com/200/200/"});


  $scope.selectItem=function(item){        
    $scope.selectedItem=item;
  };


});
```

Now in the page, we will use [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) method to loop through the items collection and print the widget

```
  <div class="thumb" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="{{item.url}}" alt="">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="caption post-content">
          <h4>{{item.name}}</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="post-meta">
          <button ng-click="selectItem(item)">SELECT</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see the when user clicks on the SELECT button, we are alling the selectItem method and passing in the current item and that will become the new selectedItem.

Here is a working sample on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xiruzutazo/edit?html,css,js,console,output)